# Remove screen from drawerNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have react native problem with react navigation v2 and drawerNavigator. Actually, I want drawerNavigator (header) to showup on screen, but I don't want that page in drawer to show.

There is my main drawer and I want to display it also on ActionPage, but I don't want Action inside it.

```
    const MainDrawer = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'POČETNA',
      }
    },
    OrderP: {
      screen: OrderStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'NARUČI',
      }
    },
    CatalogP: {
      screen: CatalogStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'KATALOZI',
      }
    },
    InstructionP: {
      screen: InstructionStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'UPUTSTVO ZA PORUČIVANJE',
      }
    },
    InfoP: {
      screen: InfoStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'INFORMACIJE O APLIKACIJI'
      }
    },
    ActionP: {
      screen: ActionStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
        title: ''
      }
    }
  }
);
```

And root stack:

```
const RootStack = StackNavigator(
  {
    MainDrawer: {
      screen: MainDrawer,
    },
    Contact: {
      screen: ContactPage
    },
    ActionP: {
      screen: ActionPage
    },
    News: {
      screen: NewsPage
    }
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to hide the pages you want, you can adapt this code:

```
// this const is used to hide desired pages
const hiddenDrawerItems = [
  'Home',
  'Profile',
]

const MainDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomePage },
    Profile: { screen: ProfilePage },
    // other pages
  },
  {
    // this entry is used to actually hide you pages
    contentComponent: (props) => {
      const clonedProps = {
        ...props,
        items: props.items.filter(item => !hiddenDrawerItems.includes(item.key)),
      }
      return <DrawerPage {...clonedProps} />
    },
  },
)
```